# The maximum number of images that Jssor slider supports and making it unlimited

Tags: jquery, jssor

I really like Jssor Slider! It has many features and it is easy to use.

In my system, images load upon user request and the numbers could be in thousands. My question is the following.

```
1. Is there a number cap by Jssor slider? 
2. If so, how much is the limit? 
3. Where can I make it unlimited? 
4. What is the consequence of making it unlimited?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of slides is unlimited in theory.

The actual limit may be your RAM. The performance should be good even there are hundreds of slides.

So get more RAM.
Then it will work maybe with 64gb RAM.

Comment: I have been keeping improve performance. And I will apply to jssor slider when I know more. Thanks for your question.

Comment: Use lazy loading. Make your image the same size as the 'slides' container. Move high performance consuming elements (like flash, video etc.) away from your slider.

Comment: Also, you can try to set $HWA (hardware acceleration) to false.

Comment: Lazy load might be very cool for list of images but the problem is, it doesn't look good when the image is loading while it is on slideshow. It would be cool if it is possible to pre-load 2 images ahead so that the user don't see images loading during slideshow. Would you please recommend me a lazy load plugin that work well with jssor slider. Thank you!

Comment: Do you think it help to set $LazyLoading to 2. It will preload images for 2 adjacent slides.

Comment: Yes that would be great!